# How can I work out the standard deviation of a t-distribution?

Tags: standard-deviation, degrees-of-freedom, t-distribution

Given a t-distribution with a certain degrees of freedom, how can I work out what the standard deviation of that distribution is?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}$ for $\nu \gt 2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the population standard deviation by computing the variance via integration and then taking the square root. (It's not the only possible way to compute a variance but it's fairly routine integration for this problem.)

Assuming you have a t$_{(\mu,\sigma^2,\nu)}$ distribution, you can replace $\mu$ by 0 without changing the variance. You can reparameterize to get rid of $\sigma$ (the variance is $\sigma^2$ times that of a standard t). Note that $\nu$ is the degrees of freedom. The location $\mu$ will only be the mean when it exists and $\sigma$ is a scale parameter but $\sigma^2$ is not the variance.

So you're left with finding the variance of a standard t$_\nu$.

$$f(x) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2})} {\sqrt{\nu\pi}\,\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} \left(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu} \right)^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}},$$

So

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)dx = 2c\int_0^\infty x^2(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}dx$$

where $c$ is the constant term out the front. There are a number of ways to approach that.

You could write that as $2c\nu$ times an integral with $x^2/\nu$ in it, then add 1 and subtract 1, pull off the -1 term into a separate integral (easily done), so you end up with a different power (and so a different $\nu$, $\nu^*$ say). You then rescale $x$ to that new  $\nu^*$ and pull out the appropriate constant to leave something times $\int_0^\infty (1+\frac{x^2}{\nu^*})^{-\frac{\nu^*+1}{2}}dx$, supply the required constant to make that a pdf (multiply and divide by by that constant), cancel the integral of a pdf out, and you're left with constant terms being a function of $\nu$.

An alternative would be to recognize something like a beta of the second kind in the integral $\int_0^\infty x^2(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}dx$. Or there are other approaches to doing the integral.

The required result is given on the [Wikipedia page for the distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), though, so if you just need the result for the standard t, you can get it there -- $\text{Var}(X)=\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}$, so $\text{sd}(X)=\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}$.

Comment: +1 A straightforward way is to introduce an inverse scale factor $y$ explicitly in the integrand so it becomes $\left(1 + y^2x^2/\nu\right)^{-(\nu+1)/2}ydx$ and differentiate the integral with respect to it. The result, easily calculated, is a linear combination of $t_\nu$ and $x^2$ times $t_{\nu+2}$ integrands, whence they can be found simply by knowing the constant term $c(\nu)$. But since this rescaling does not change the total probability, the derivative is zero, giving an easy solution for the expectation of $x^2$ relative to $t_{\nu+2}$.

Comment: @whuber Oh, that's better/neater.

Comment: I do actually need to result just for the standard t. I know this is a silly question, but what is v?

Comment: $\nu$ ("[nu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_%28letter%29)") is the degrees of freedom in the $t$. It's discussed in the link in my answer, more specifically it's defined to be the d.f. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Probability_density_function)

Comment: Oh, and it's *not* a silly question to ask for clarification of whatever's not clear; it seems like a very important question. I've added a couple of sentences to explain what the parameters of the $t$ are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic equation for standard deviation assuming you only have a **sample** of the whole population.

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$

1. Get the mean of the distribution ($\bar{x}$)
2. Subtract the mean from each number in the vector ($x_i$) and square the result $(x_i - \bar{x})^2$
3. Sum the results and multiply by (1/total_number - 1) ($\frac{1}{n-1}$)
4. Take the square root

If you have the entire population the equation is:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)^2}$$

Comment: What are $x_i$s? This answer seems unrelated to working out the standard deviation of a $t$-distribution.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala, I must have misunderstood the question.  I assumed the author had a vector of numbers from a t-distribution.  These equations are the basic formulas for calculating standard deviation.  Judging by the above answer, the question is not such a simple scenario.  I have clarified the notation in the answer.